# PhpStorm - Inspections about NULL value

Tags: php, phpstorm

Question about this example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class SomeTestClass
{
    /** @var string|null */
    private $name;

    /** @var string */
    private $sth;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setSomething(string $value): void
    {
        $this->sth = $value;
    }

    public function something(): void
    {
        $this->setSomething($this->getName());
    }
}
```

Why *PhpStorm 2018.3.5* is not informing me about wrong code in `something()` related to using nullable value as a method argument which should not be nullable? I'm asking about this because when `$name` property will be `null`, then I would have an error in my app.

Version with

```php
public function something(): void
{
    /** @var string|null $name */
    $name = $this->getName();
    $this->setSomething($name);
}
```

also does not work.

Comment: Couldn't you put some comment above the something() method?

Comment: @LiamRoels What kind of comment do you mean :)?

Comment: I don't think PHPStorm does this, you could however use a tool like PHPStan, to find these issues for you.

Comment: just a phpdoc comment in which you describe the expected type of return

Comment: It has to be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16072 or one of the related tickets.

Comment: Which version of PHP is PHPStorm working on?

Comment: @LiamRoels Setting PhpDocs above all methods also does not work.

Comment: @gbalduzzi I have PHP 7.1 set in settings. Does it work for you on others?

Comment: I can replicate this in 2018.3.5 with PHP 7.2 inspection. Code definitely results in a fatal and I'm unable to convince PHPStorm that there's anything wrong - even PHPDoc with just `NULL` as the return for `getName` doesn't give a warning.

Comment: also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15078. Not yet implemented in PhpStorm

Answer (score 3):

PhpStorm is not very strict when analysing code. For example, when injecting property values through constructor, it does not look at declared property type when autocompleting methods and properties, but rather at the type that was injected into constructor.

For very strict analysis, try out [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan). Unlike PhpStorm, you can easily add it to your CI build. [See the resulting error for your example](https://phpstan.org/r/2bad29b9-c8d0-40d5-9a0c-4e479db65530).

Answer (score 0):

I think PhpStorm inspection is broken with instance variables type annotations.

If I use directly:

```
$this->setSomething(null);
```

I get the type error. 
However, if I directly assign null to `$this->sth`, I get no error at all:

```
$this->sth = null;
```

Basically, don't rely on variable type annotations to be correctly inspected with `strict_types=1`